# How to run multiple test files in a go package

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

I have a project structure like this:

```
pkg
|
--pkg.go
--pkg_test.go
--a.go
--a_test.go
--b.go
--b_test.go
--c.go
--c_test.go
```

I wish to get the coverage for all the source files belonging to the package i.e.(pkg.go, a.go, b.go and c.go). However, when I run:

`go test -v pkg`

tests are run for only 1/4 go files.

Is there any way I can test my package without moving all the test codes within one file and keeping the file structure intact ?

Comment: "tests are run for only 1/4 go files". No. Like all normal .go files are compiled into a package **all** _test.go files are part of the test and the coverage report (unless explicitly excluded by build constraints). You are doing something wrong.

Comment: You mean to say that go test -v pkg should be running all the test cause ? Can you please point me places where I might have gone wrong ?

Comment: I'm not saying it "should" run all the the test, I say it _does_ run all the tests. Things to look for: 1. The obvious: You interpret the coverage result wrong (most likely and you did not show the actual output, what you expect and why you expect the different outcome than the actual one). 2. Build constraints. 3. Skipped tests. 4. Typo in the file name like _test**s**.go. I'd bet on 1.

Answer (score 3):

if your working directory is that of your package, to test all of the files you could run:

```
go test ./...
```

if you wanted to get test coverage, you could run:

```
go test ./... -cover
```

Comment: Why did this get a downvote?  Does it not answer the question/not work?

Comment: This is fine to run, but the question only contains one package.

Comment: Ah yes, that is why I specified you should be in the package directory when running it.  I am not sure you can specify packages when running `go test`.

Comment: Look at the usage for `go test`, the arguments after flags is one or more package names. (the relative path wildcard `./...` itself resolves to one or more package names)